# AlarmManager not working Properly in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background, alarmmanager

Actually I wanna run background thread after specific time like after 10 seconds to send Api to server but first I am trying below code for checking/testing. In AlarmReceiver Class onReceive run only one time rather I want to run after every 10 seconds. I am new to android please guide me how can I achieve my goal. Thanks

Here is MainActivity Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    }


    public void startAlarm(View view) {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000; // 10 seconds

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(View view) {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is AlarmReceiver Class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Here is Manifest File code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.majidali.alarammanager">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: why dont you try handler since you need every 10 seconds

Comment: then please tell me how can I implement handler?

Comment: I am new to android I don't  know how I can implement handler?

Comment: try my answer and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for small time difference like seconds , You can use **`Handler`**.

Try this code,

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable mytask=new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //do something
         Toast.makeText(Youractivity.this, "Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);//10 sec
    }
};
mytask.run();
```

## Edit

Do some trick,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //yourtask
        setAlarm(context,10000);

    }
    public void setAlarm(Context context,long time)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + time, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And in your Activity,

```
new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(this,10000);
```

Comment: but I want to do  this functionality even app is active or not

Comment: if app is not active or destroyed.  Will it work  under that condition?

Comment: if any reason I increase time to 5 minutes will it work properly?

Comment: it will work . But if you want to do even if app closed, then better to choose alarm manager or service

Comment: I have choose AlarmManager but not working in every 10 seconds  please see my code or give me an example thanks a lot

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: could you explain for me where is recursion going on?And how @Override onReceive function  calling again and again thanks

Comment: setRepeating()  may cause a problem . So I have used set() and when you receive the alarm in onReceive(), I am again setting the alarm . Check onReceive() method

Comment: Thanks :) Your are very kind